# Conspiracy Theorist Hat counting procedure

Tags: discussion, winter-bash-2013

The conspiracy theorist hat in Winter Bash is awarded on total number of flags or the flags done after the start of Winter Bash.?

Comment: see my answer below but I fear it is the later.

Comment: Yes it is the later one.

Comment: Conspiracy Theorist works just like Defender of the Realm, but with more flags. Only *new* flags count; I would have been awarded the hats immediately when Winterbash started otherwise.

Answer (score 4):

Only the flags after the start  the Winter Bash, and it only counts for VLQ, NAA, spam, offensive, and 'Other' flags. It doesn't count for off-topic, duplicate and unclear what you're asking flags, because 3k+ users would vote to close instead of flag these posts.

Answer (score 3):

The second one I fear.

I have 158 helpful flags on SharePoint and still no hat (see [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/flag-summary/5173)), so it must only work for new flags. Which is a shame, we don't get many flags on SharePoint.